# Autoincrement vs composite primary key for a big table on innodb

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, primary-key, clustered-primary-key

I have a had a quite lengthy discussion with Rick James on this this we came out with idea of having composite key to replace the autoincrement pk where the int is limited close 2 billion. My table will reach this limit in few months easily as monthly we are capturing close to few hundred million data. Below is how my table looks like. The key table is the `gdata` so I composite the primary using 3 fields `PRIMARY KEY (alarmTypeID,vehicleID,gDateTime)`. Then I have another table called alarm table. The link between both is one to many. Meaning one data in `gdata` can have zero or more `alarms` related to it. The link between them is `vehicleID` and `gDateTime`.

```
CREATE TABLE `gdata` ( 
    `alarmTypeID` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `fleetID` smallint(11) NOT NULL, 
    `fleetGroupID` smallint(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `fleetSubGroupID` smallint(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `deviceID` mediumint(11) NOT NULL, 
    `vehicleID` mediumint(11) NOT NULL, 
    `gDateTime` datetime NOT NULL, 
    `insertDateTime` datetime NOT NULL, 
    `latitude` float NOT NULL, 
    `longitude` float NOT NULL, 
    `speed` smallint(11) NOT NULL
     -- (see full text) 
) ;
ALTER TABLE `gdata` 
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`alarmTypeID`,`vehicleID`,`gDateTime`), 
    ADD KEY `gDateTime` (`gDateTime`), 
    ADD KEY `fleetID` (`fleetID`,`vehicleID`,`gDateTime`); 
COMMIT;
```

Here is the alarm table

```
CREATE TABLE `alarm` (
    `alarmTypeID` tinyint(4) NOT NULL, 
    `vehicleID` mediumint(9) NOT NULL, 
    `gDateTime` datetime NOT NULL, 
    `insertDateTime` datetime NOT NULL, 
    `alarmValue` varchar(5) NOT NULL, 
    `readWeb` enum('n','y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n', 
    `readWebDateTime` datetime NOT NULL, 
    `readMobile` enum('n','y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n', 
    `readMobileDateTim` datetime NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 

ALTER TABLE `alarm` 
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`alarmTypeID`,`vehicleID`,`gDateTime`); 
COMMIT;
```

All looks good but recently I was doing some googling on related topic and found that some discussion https://www.quora.com/Is-it-a-bad-idea-to-have-a-primary-key-on-3-or-more-columns are against composite primary key and would prefer to go with autoincrement mainly for insert purpose. Can some one shed more light on this to maintain composite key of primary or move back to autoincrement?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61883/discussion-on-question-by-user8012596-autoincrement-vs-composite-primary-key-for).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with a composite key. However, you have to take into account [how `InnoDB` stores data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-row-format-overview.html).

Quoting the above linked documentation:

> The data in each InnoDB table is divided into pages. The pages that make up each table are arranged in a tree data structure called a B-tree index. Table data and secondary indexes both use this type of structure. The B-tree index that represents an entire table is known as the **clustered index**, which is **organized according to the primary key columns**. The nodes of the index data structure contain the values of all the columns in that row (for the clustered index) or the index columns and the primary key columns (for secondary indexes).

That is, InnoDB will store the data according to your `PRIMARY KEY`. If the data you're inserting has an increasing PK, page fragmentation does not occur. That will happen always with an `AUTO_INCREMENT`. If you're inserting the data in *chronological order* (i.e. `gDateTime` is always monotonically increasing), changing the *order* of the columns that make out your PK to:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`gDateTime`, `alarmTypeID`, `vehicleID`)
```

... will have the same advantages, with regard to not having to "fit a new row in the middle of others" (which means, the B-tree isn't fragmented for every insert).

However: if you reference this table from other (related) tables, you have to store, in the referencing table always the PK (`gDateTime`, `alarmTypeID`, `vehicleID`). This means you're saving every time 7 or 8 bytes of storage. The composite PK would use 2 + 1 + 8 = 11 bytes of information (probably it uses 12 bytes due to alignment); whereas an `INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT`, you'll use only 4 bytes in the referencing table. You're limited to a 2^32 different values for your PK. If you need more than 2^32 values, you'll need `BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT`, that gives you 2^64 (and I haven't found yet a practical case where this isn't big enough).

Whether this makes sense or not, depends a lot on your particular scenario.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61884/discussion-on-answer-by-joanolo-autoincrement-vs-composite-primary-key-for-a-big).

Answer (score 4):

joanolo has some good points, and some points I will disagree with...

- As of 5.6.4, `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP`, without fractional seconds, each take 5 bytes.  (So the PK in question is a total of 9 bytes.)
- Fragmentation in the data is not that bad.  And, if it allows for significant improvement in other actions, it may be worth it.  (See below.)  A BTree inherently settles down to about 69% full.  (A block split turns a 100% full block into two 50% full blocks, then they both gradually refill.)
- Using a `DATETIME` (or `TIMESTAMP`) in a `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` key is dangerous -- what if two entries happen at exactly the same time?  (This question is application dependent; for example, measuring the location of a truck does not need two gps readings within a second.)
- The link about PKs talks about "fat" PKs.  The PK in question is only 9 bytes--not really fat.  So the link is only mildly relevant.  Furthermore, fatness only applies when you have at least 2 secondary indexes that do not include the fat columns.
- The table is threatening to overflow a 4-byte `INT`, the next choice for `AUTO_INCREMENT` is an 8-byte `BIGINT`; not much different than 9 bytes.
- `MEDIUMINT` is 3 bytes (`vehicleID`).
- I'm pretty sure there is *no* "alignment" of fields in InnoDB structures.  InnoDB is designed such that the files are compatible across all hardware architectures.
- MySQL *requires* that the PK be unique.  If dropping out alarmTypeID removes uniqueness, *do not do it*!

Specifics...

```
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`alarmTypeID`,`vehicleID`,`gDateTime`), -- 1+3+5 = 0 bytes
ADD KEY `gDateTime` (`gDateTime`),                       -- 5 + 1+3 = 9
ADD KEY `fleetID` (`fleetID`,`vehicleID`,`gDateTime`);   -- 2+3+5 + 1 = 11
```

I say 0 bytes for the PK because it is included with the rest of the columns.
The numbers for secondary keys are the sizes of the secondary key columns + extra PK columns.
(There is, of course, significant overhead in an index, so these numbers can't be used to compute the ultimate size of the BTree.  You might need a fudge-factor of 3x.)

A `SELECT` with

```
WHERE alarmTypeID = constant
  AND vehicleID = constant
  AND gDateTime ... (some range)
```

is much better handled by (`alarmTypeID`,`vehicleID`,`gDateTime`) than by (`gDateTime`, `alarmTypeID`, `vehicleID`).  If this is a common query, I contend that it outweighs the desire to avoid fragmentation.

PRIMARY KEY(`alarmTypeID`,`vehicleID`,`gDateTime`) avoids bouncing between the secondary key and the data.

PRIMARY KEY(`gDateTime`, `alarmTypeID`, `vehicleID`) cannot use alarm or vehicle, and would have to step over alarms and vehicles that are not of interest.  Or use a secondary key, leading to bouncing back and forth.  In either case, much slower.  (Rule of Thumb: 10x slower for spinning disks when the data is not cached.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61885/discussion-on-answer-by-rick-james-autoincrement-vs-composite-primary-key-for-a).